# VLC stopped producing sound on macOS

Tags: vlc-media-player

This week all my usual files stopped producing sound on VLC. VLC still shows the video and the files play with sound on other programs like QuickTime. I checked the output of the computer, the volume of the computer, and the volume of VLC. I also reinstalled VLC, which is 3.0.11.1 and macOS is 10.14.6.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had played a file on different speakers. Even though I had chosen that on the macOS top bar, VLC stuck with it after I disconnected the speakers. You can check the output device of VLC on the menu bar: `Audio > Audio Device > Built-in Output` or make it coincide with the system output with `System Sound Output Device`.

[image: choose audio device in VLC]